# Port forwarding not working with IIS Express

Tags: router, dns, port-forwarding, webserver, iis

Right. This could be posted on either StackOverflow or here, becuz the scenario I'm working with involves both network settings and IIS configuration, but I'm posting here since I guess that's where it's stuck at the moment.

OK. I'm trying to setup a test website on my machine which connects to the Internet through a router (ZXDSL 831 CII). I've done the following:

1. Created a dynamic DNS entry, say `myserver.chickenkiller.com` using afraid.org. Works fine.
2. Configured Virtual Server on my router to forward incoming traffic on port `12345` to be forwarded to my local IP address (192.168.1.3).
3. Enabled IIS Express on my local machine to run with admin privileges.
4. Configured `applicationhost.config` to allow external connections.
5. When I test my machine using a [port checking tool](http://www.ipmango.com/network/port_forward), it tells me that the port `12345` is open.
6. Trying to reach `myserver.chickenkiller.com:12345` through the browser first shows "Resolving host", then says "Connecting..."  and then after waiting for maybe 15 seconds, and then ends up with "Could not connect". Same thing happens when I type this address on another (virtual) machine.

I need to figure out where the problem lies. Is it my ISP blocking traffic from reaching my router (unlikely in my opinion), or is it the router not forwarding the packets to my machine, or is it the web server (IIS Express) not handling the requests. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: From the web server, what is the result for `netstat -an | find "12345"` ?

Comment: @user2196728: TCP    0.0.0.0:25094          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    192.168.1.3:25094      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:25094             [::]:0                 LISTENING

Comment: Ok so now let's try this : from another machine in your local network try `telnet 192.168.1.3 25084` and tell us if it fails or not.